# Using Spring Java Config to register Apache Camel dataFormats

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel version 2.10.0 and I currently have the following in my camelContext in XML format:

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="jack" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="package.name.PojoClassName"/>
</dataFormats>
```

I want to move it to Java Config, but I can't seem to do it without using a deprecated method. This is a trimmed down version of what I got:

```
public class MyCamelConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected void setupCamelContext(CamelContext context) {
        // "getDataFormats()" is deprecated
        context.getDataFormats().put("jack", getJack());
    }

    @Override
    public List<RouteBuilder> routes() {
        // bunch of route builders created and returned
    }

    @Bean
    public DataFormatDefinition getJack() {
        //create and return a DataFormatDefinition
    }
}
```

I have been unable to find a non-deprecated way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following works:

```
@Override
protected void setupCamelContext(CamelContext context) {
    ModelCamelContext modelContext = (ModelCamelContext) context;
    modelContext.getDataFormats().put("jack", getJack());
}
```

I just cast the `CamelContext` to a `ModelCamelContext`.